# .NET Core 2.0 Partial views with one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, partial-views

I am working with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and I am trying use a partial view to list some items.

I have these two models

```
public class Person {
    [Key]
    public String PersonID {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Item {
    //PersonID and ItemName make the Primary key
    public String PersonID {get; set;} //Foreign Key to Person
    public String ItemName{get; set;}
    public String Description {get; set;}

    public Person Person {get; set;}
}
```

I have a view that displays the information that is from the Person table.  Underneath that I want to render a partial view that lists the items that person has. I have created a partial view but I have no idea how to either call a controller function to query the db or pass a list of the items to it.

Comment: Ideally, when you're rendering a partial view from within a parent view, the parent view should already have the necessary view-model to pass onto the partial view. Otherwise, you'll have to resort to a child-action instead (`Html.Action(...)`)

Comment: Re-reading your question, I assume you already have the entire `Item` model, along with its `Person` (one-to-one) relationship loaded. Then, assuming the view-model of that partial is your `Person`, why can't you just call `@Html.Partial("PartialName", Model.Person)`?

Comment: @haim770 I have the Person model in my display page. I had wanted to pass the PersonID off to the controller and have it fetch the items and then send those to the Partial View to display in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a PersonViewModel like this:

```
class PersonViewModel
{
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then fill this model with data in your controller. Then pass this model to your Person view, and create a partial view for each Item like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Items)
{
    @Html.Partial("ItemPartial", item)
}
```

If you need more help with this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use this in view to render partial view `@Html.Action("ActionResult method","ControllerName")`.

controller method

```
public ActionResult MethodName()
{
    //Your logic to get and fill the data in model
    return View("_PartialViewName",model);
}
```

Comment: When I put the `@Html.Action()` in the View. It tells me _'IHtmlHelper<Person>' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and the best extension method overload 'UrlHelperExtensions.Action(IUrlHelper, string, object)' requires a receiver of type 'IUrlHelper'_     Do you know what I need to do to fix that?